# Is it possible to make a POST to a file saved on github?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a repository and put a db.json file in its root. I used a json server to host this file at https://my-json-server.typicode.com/priscilasilvaalves/jsoncaixaentrada.github.io/db . In my code, I fetch that address and try to use the POST method to save a message to that file. But I get 404 Not Found error with Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin. How could I do a POST to a file hosted on github? It's possible?

My function is:

```
const [nome, setNome] = useState("");
const [mensagem, setMensagem] = useState("");

async function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
            const conexao = await fetch("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/priscilasilvaalves/jsoncaixaentrada.github.io/db", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    nome: nome,
                    mensagem: mensagem
                }),
            })
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't do this for the reason you've discovered - CORS is not enabled. I'm not sure why you'd ever want to do this. Just host the file yourself somewhere. Also note that you really shouldn't be making a POST request to a static file. GET makes far more sense, but this still won't fix your CORS problem.

Comment: Github hosts repositories, not files. The only way to "upload" something there is to commit and push with git. Look at something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git , but bear in mind that you'll need ssh keys set up to be able to push.